# Memory leak on IOS9-VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame

Tags: memory-leaks, ios9, decode, video-toolbox

I use the Video tool box, to decode h264 data on IOS8.x. When this code run on IOS 9.x, I got a memory leak every time I call VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame, and I can't see any memory leak in Instruments tool!

here is the code:
https://github.com/stevenyao/iOSHardwareDecoder

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing a memory leak on device when processing the hardware decoded frame in a background thread, but I then copied the YUV frame to a BGRA frame via CoreImage and then passed the BGRA frame back to the main thread so that it could be turned into a UIImage. At that point, the leak went away.